# if empty allow update or !empty not allowed update

Tags: php

I have a table with fields (id, status, reason, sid)
Field as Linked table reg

See this code:

```
<?php


include "config.php";


/*
CREATE TABLE  `reg` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `id_number` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `birthdate` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `mobile` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `qualification` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `project` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `project_type` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `experience` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `notes` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `date` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;


*/
/// STATUS
/*
CREATE TABLE  `status` (
 `sid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `status` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
 `reason` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `id` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
*/


$gid = intval($_GET['id']);
$id = $_POST['id'];
$n = $_POST['name'];
$i = $_POST['id_number'];
$b = $_POST['birthdate'];
$m = $_POST['mobile'];
$q = $_POST['qualification'];
$e = $_POST['email'];
$p = $_POST['project'];
$pt = $_POST['project_type'];
$ex = $_POST['experience'];
$no = $_POST['notes'];


// STATUS
$sid = $_POST['id'];
$status = strip_tags($_POST['status']);
$reason = strip_tags($_POST['reason']);


if (isset($_POST['nstatus']) and $_POST['nstatus'] == 'stat'){
    $insertstatus = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO status (id,status,reason) VALUES ('$sid','$status','$reason')") or die ("mysql error");
        if (isset ($insertstatus)){
            die ("Update Is Done
            <meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; url=show_reg.php' />");
            }
    }
// STATUS END


if (isset($_POST['edit']) and $_POST['edit'] == 'reg'){
    $update = mysql_query ("UPDATE reg SET name='$n',id_number='$i',birthdate='$b',mobile='$m',qualification='$q',email='$e',project='$p',  project_type='$pt',experience='$ex',notes='$no' WHERE id='$id'") or die ("mysql error");
    if (isset($update)){
        echo "<h2>Update is done</h2>";
        }   
    }
if ($_REQUEST['del'] == 'reg'){
    $del = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM reg WHERE id='".$gid."'");
    if (isset ($del)){
        echo "<h2>Delete is done</h2>";
        }
    }
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg WHERE id='".$gid."'") or die ("mysql error");
$rowedit = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'edit'){
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
<table border='1' width='750' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='text' name='name' value='".$rowedit['name']."' /></td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='text' name='id_number' value='".$rowedit['id_number']."' /></td>
        <td>Id Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='date' name='birthdate' value='".$rowedit['birthdate']."' /></td>
        <td>Birthdate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='number' name='mobile' value='".$rowedit['mobile']."' /></td>
        <td>Mobile No.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='text' name='qualification' value='".$rowedit['qualification']."' /></td>
        <td>Qualification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='email' name='email' value='".$rowedit['email']."' /></td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='text' name='project' value='".$rowedit['project']."' /></td>
        <td>Project Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Busines</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='project_type' value='Busines' /></td>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td><input type='radio'  name='project_type' value='Home' /></td>
        <td>Project Type</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><input type='text' name='experience' value='".$rowedit['experience']."' /></td>
        <td>Experience</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><textarea style='width:300px; height:50px;' name='notes'>".$rowedit['notes']."</textarea></td>
        <td>Notes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' value='Save' />
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$gid."' />
<input type='hidden' name='edit' value='reg' />
</form>";}
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg ORDER BY id DESC");
$gid = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg WHERE id='".$gid."'") or die ("mysql error");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (!isset ($gid)){
    die ("<h2>Input is incorrect</h2>");
    }
else if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){
    die ("<h2>No data in the database</h2>");
    }else if (isset($gid) and is_numeric($gid)) {
    echo "<table width='80%' cellpadding='5' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Id Number</td>
            <td>Birthdate</td>
            <td>Mobile No.</td>
            <td>Qualification </td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Project</td>
            <td>Project Type</td>
            <td>Experience</td>
            <td>Notes</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Options</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>".$row['id']."</td>
            <td>".$row['name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['id_number']."</td>
            <td>".$row['birthdate']."</td>
            <td>".$row['mobile']."</td>
            <td>".$row['qualification']."</td>
            <td>".$row['email']."</td>
            <td>".$row['project']."</td>
            <td>".$row['project_type']."</td>
            <td>".$row['experience']."</td>
            <td>".$row['notes']."</td>
            <td>".$row['date']."</td>
            <td>
            <a href='show_reg_more.php?do=edit&id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a>- 
            <a href='show_reg_more.php?del=reg&id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>
            </td>


        </tr>       
        </table>";


// START STATUS
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
<table width='80%' border='1' cellpadding='5'>
<tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='2'>Add Status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Yes<input type='radio' name='status' value='Yes' /></br>
    No<input type='radio' name='status' value='No' /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Reason Rejection</td>
    <td><textarea name='reason'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Status' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='hidden' name='nstatus' value='stat' />
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$gid."' />


</form>";
// END STATUS       
    }else {
        echo "<h2>No Results</h2>";
        }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If the field (status) is empty then I want to allow update and not allow update if the field is not empty.

How can I write the code for IF in PHP

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you want to know if $_POST['status'] is empty, then just use `if( isset($_POST['status']) )`

Comment: Please use http://us1.php.net/mysqli or http://us1.php.net/pdo ! MySQL is deprecated. And use prepared Statements for your own security. And look at some Coding Standards.

Comment: @PhilippMurry Why not using http://us1.php.net/empty     empty()

Comment: and ? ? ? ? funny to see it there :D

Comment: @Webice what what? look at the if else, i haven't seen if ( a and b ) since like ages :D

Comment: @k0sh Whoa yeah thats cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that ?

```
$status = strip_tags($_POST['status']);
if (isset($_POST['nstatus']) && $_POST['nstatus'] == 'stat') {
    if (empty($status)) {
        $insertstatus = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO status (id,status,reason) VALUES ('$sid','$status','$reason')") or die ("mysql error");
        if($insertstatus) {
            die ("Update us done <meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; url=show_reg.php' />");
        } else {
            die("An Error occured.");
        }
    } else {
         die ("Has recently added");
    }
}
```

Comment: $_POST['status'] and $_POST['nstatus'] exists in that Script  :)

Attention on the N

Comment: Open your eyes. Dont sleep anymore and read the (crap) code correctly !

Comment: @k0sh I thought the Code is not what he want. But i dont know what he want. But its correctly. ;) No Problem mate !

Comment: Please could you explain what your solution is to complement the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Does not work 
Required: 
When you add (status) is to make sure that the field does not contain any valuable input.
If there is no value entered data